# How do I keep my homemade liquid fabric softener from separating?

Tags: bond, water, solutions, materials, mixtures

I have a recipe for a homemade liquid fabric softener that smells good and works great, but I have to shake it every time before I use it. It gets old fast.
The recipe calls for:
12 cups hot water, almost to boil
6 cups distilled white vinegar
4 cups of favorite hair conditioner
1 cup baking soda
Mix hot water and conditioner completely
Mix in vinegar completely
Mix in baking soda slowly till it no longer rises then add all the rest and mix completely. Set aside for a few hours and then mix it back together and done.
Well, no not done cause it won't stay together....please help

Comment: Any other methods you've tried?

Comment: This is not a good idea to use fabric softener like this. You final rinse will have all these unwanted chemicals on your clothes, towels, bedsheets. Hair conditioner is meant for a temporary exposure.

Comment: Don't the vinegar and baking soda mostly destroy each other?

Comment: Maybe adding some soap might help. Taking chunk out of the soap in your bathroom and grinding it, or purchasing some sodium hydroxide and mixing with leftover oil.

Comment: Though the recipe seems pointless, to keep material from separating, you might try ultrasonic homogenization.